# CSOM How do I clear a TaxonomyField on a library item?

Tags: taxonomyfieldvalue

I need to remove managed metadata tagging on a taxonomy field for a library item.
How do I do that?

I have tried:

```
TaxonomyFieldValue emptyTermValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue
{
    Label = string.Empty,
    TermGuid = string.Empty
};
taxonomyField.SetFieldValueByValue(item, emptyTermValue);
```

However, there is an error and the Term tag is retained after `context.ExecuteQuery()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create an `empty` TaxonomyFieldValue object, use a `null` value instead.

Sample of code:

```
Field field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
TaxonomyField txField = clientContext.CastTo(field);
txField.ValidateSetValue(listItem, null);
item.Update();
ctx.Load(item);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Source: [Update/Clear Taxonomy Field Value using C# CSOM](https://unnieayilliath.com/2015/08/24/sharepoint-2013-updateclear-taxonomy-field-value-using-c-csom/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Thank you @jleture, this worked!